# How to estimate gas without balance?

Tags: gas, contract-invocation, web3.py, gas-estimate

So, I'm making a private network and deploying some contracts. The contract has a payable method which means I have to put value when calling the method. I want to get the estimated cost to call the method using this function in web3.py

```py
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
transaction = contract.functions.someMethod().buildTransaction({
    'from': someUserAddress,
    'value': someValue
})
print(w3.eth.estimate_gas(transaction))
```

This works fine for user that has balance in their wallet. But, for user that has 0 balance in their wallet, this method is not working. This error must be show up

```py
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address <someUserAddress> have 0 want <someValue> (supplied gas xxxxxxx)'}
```

I need to estimate gas first so the user can know how much they must top up the balance to call the method and not blindly to up the balance. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same problem here

Comment: @sigmaxf same, found something? haha

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are bootstrapping private Ethereum network.

First of all, when you have `payable` function, you are not forced to send value into it, but you are able to.

Secondly, you have to pay gas for your transaction and that is probably your issue. If your user has 0 balance, he/she is not able to send transaction even when transferred value is 0.

You can find more how to estimate gas usage in web3.py here: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html?highlight=gas%20estimate#web3.contract.ContractFunction.estimateGas

Comment: No, the value can't be zero because I make the method revert when the value is not the same as the value inside the contract. And no, the problem is not the gas, but the value. Because when I tried to estimateGas non-payable method, I could still do it with 0 balance.

Comment: I would say that problem is with `buildTransaction`. Have you tried this `my_contract.functions.foo(3, 2, 1).estimateGas()`?

Comment: Yup... The problem persist. It's the same error. If I set the value, web3 will be checking if my balance is at least equal the value.

Comment: It's wierd if the problem is with buildTransaction because I tried it with non-payable method and using buildTransaction has no problem with it.